# sketch on arduino stops executing in object constructor

Tags: c++, arduino

Since there is no debugging utility on arduino (or at least i am not familliar with) it is hard to follow the code and see where it is stopped...
below i iattached my setup function. inside setup i creat an object of init class.. its constructor take care of initializing EEPROM data for mission time etc . but by adding several serial output i found that program wont get out of init class. when i comment init, everything works fine. i checked all line of   init class but found no problem

```
       void setup() {

         Serial.begin(9600);
       pinMode(ARM_BUTTON_PIN,INPUT);
    Serial.println("start");
    //   EEPROM.put(PACKET_COUNT_EEPROM, 0);

 Init init;
 Serial.println("before Contoll");

controller= new Controller();


Serial.println("setup");

delay(200);}
```

this is init.cpp:

```
   #include "constants.h"
   #include "Sampler.h"
    #include "SDLogger.h"
   #include "Controller.h"
    #include "Init.h"

/*
 * EEPROM Structure
 * 0: @: 0 mission Time(s) uint16_t
 * 1: @: sizeof(uint16_t) packetCount uint16_t
 * 2: @: sizeof(uint16_t)+ sizeof(uint16_t) stateCode uint8_t
 * 3: @: sizeof(uint16_t)+ sizeof(uint16_t) + sizeof(uint8_t)  refAltitude int16_t 
#define MISSION_TIME_EEPROM 0
#define PACKET_COUNT_EEPROM sizeof(uint16_t)
#define STATE_CODE_EEPROM sizeof(uint16_t)+ sizeof(uint16_t) 
#define REF_ALTITUDE_EEPROM sizeof(uint16_t)+ sizeof(uint16_t) + sizeof(uint8_t) 
 */

 Init::Init(){
    Sampler sampler;
    uint16_t missionEEPROMTime ;
    EEPROM.get(MISSION_TIME_EEPROM, missionEEPROMTime);

      Serial.println("init");
delay(100);
    if(!digitalRead(ARM_BUTTON_PIN)){

  if( missionEEPROMTime == 0 ){
    //initiate reset
    Serial.println("armed0");

    resetSystem();
    Serial.println("befin");
delay(100);

    initializeSystem();
    Serial.println("befres");

    Controller::startTime = 0;
  }  else{
    Serial.println("armednot0");

    //recover
    recoverSystem();
    Controller::startTime = missionEEPROMTime;
  }
    }else{
      Serial.println("not arm");

              resetSystem();
              Controller::startTime = 0;
         EEPROM.put(REF_ALTITUDE_EEPROM, sampler.readAltitude());
              // Serial.println(sampler.readAltitude());

        // while(1);
    }

  }


     Init::resetSystem(){
          Sampler sampler;

  for (int i = 0 ; i < EEPROM.length() ; i++) {
    EEPROM.write(i, 0);
  }
           EEPROM.put(REF_ALTITUDE_EEPROM, sampler.readAltitude());

    }
    Init::initializeSystem(){
      delay(100);
              Serial.println("vbqdfewf");


           Serial.println("initSample");

        EEPROM.put(MISSION_TIME_EEPROM, 0);
        EEPROM.put(PACKET_COUNT_EEPROM, 0);
        EEPROM.put(STATE_CODE_EEPROM, 0);
       // EEPROM.put(REF_ALTITUDE_EEPROM, sampler.readAltitude());
       // SDLogger::initCSV(0);
       // SDLogger::initIMG(0);
       // SDLogger::beginBus();
        Serial.println("inited");
    }
   Init::recoverSystem(){
      //  SDLogger::initCSV(1);
      //  SDLogger::initIMG(1);
      //  SDLogger::beginBus();

  }
```

and init.h:

```
 #ifndef Init_h
  #define Init_h

  #include "constants.h"
  #include "Sampler.h"
  #include "SDLogger.h"
  #include "Controller.h"

  /*
   * EEPROM Structure
   * 0: @: 0 mission Time(s) uint16_t
   * 1: @: sizeof(uint16_t) packetCount uint16_t
   * 2: @: sizeof(uint16_t)+ sizeof(uint16_t) stateCode uint8_t
   * 3: @: sizeof(uint16_t)+ sizeof(uint16_t) + sizeof(uint8_t)  refAltitude int16_t 
  #define MISSION_TIME_EEPROM 0
  #define PACKET_COUNT_EEPROM sizeof(uint16_t)
  #define STATE_CODE_EEPROM sizeof(uint16_t)+ sizeof(uint16_t) 
  #define REF_ALTITUDE_EEPROM sizeof(uint16_t)+ sizeof(uint16_t) + sizeof(uint8_t) 
   */
  class Init {
    public:
    Init();


    private:
      resetSystem();
      initializeSystem();
    recoverSystem();

  };
  #endif
```

other classes as in sampler and telemetery works fine when i coment init init. so there is no problem with them.

Comment: You seem to be doing an awfully lot in your constructor. Perhaps you should move most of it into some other initialization function? Also, either through an emulator or through remote debugging, you really should try to step through the code in a debugger to find out what might be the problem.

Comment: "is no debugging utility on arduino" that is simply not true. You can run simulator, jtag debugging or simply compile for pc and mock up hardware if needed. Development on a black box is not state of the art.

Comment: In addition to dude's comment: In general, you should not do any print or delay or other stuff in a c'tor. Global instances of such classes are constructed VERY early.

Answer (score 0):

This also known as the [Static Initialzation Order Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).  You have to separate the *construction* of objects (things that occur before `setup`) and their *initial procedures* (in `setup` or later).

For example, `Serial` and many other classes have a `begin()` or `init()` method that is called explicitly from the sketch.

Comment: as you can see in my code i have done everything in setup so it shouldnt be the point... after i deleted several delays() that i had it starts doing somthing...seems delay is not allowed in constructors... i am not sure ...

Comment: but anyway thanks for your info   i didnt know this.. thanks.